# In relative likelihood, why do we compare other estimated parameter values to those obtained via MLE?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Relative_likelihood_function):

> Suppose that the maximum likelihood estimate for $θ$ is ${\displaystyle {\hat {\theta }}}$. Relative plausibilities of other $θ$ values may be found by comparing the likelihood of those other values with the likelihood of ${\displaystyle {\hat {\theta }}}$. The relative likelihood of $θ$ is defined as $\mathcal{L}(\theta | x)/\mathcal{L}(\hat \theta | x)$.

I don't understand why the comparison is only made between candidate parameter values to the one estimated via maximum likelihood, why can't it be applied to any two sets of candidate parameters.

For example, suppose we observe the outcomes of a sequence of Bernoulli trials. We have two estimates for the success probabilities, $(p_1, p_2, \dots)$, and $(q_1, q_2, \dots)$. Is it possible to say one set of estimates is better than the other, by using relative likelihood?

Comment: If measured relative the maximum, then relative likelihood would be in [0,1]. If the denominator were smaller than the maximum, then numbers >1 could result. Perhaps this is all that was meant? If likelihood is your metric, then I believe any ratio > 1 indicates the "better" model. (So should be OK.)